# For which values of $a$, $f$ is bijective?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I have troubles with the following problem.

For which values of $a$ the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{5}{3}x^2+ax+2$ is bijective?

I tried with the injective part in the classic form (I supposed that $f(x)=f(y) $ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$...) but I did not get nothing.

Can someone give me a hint (not the answer, please)

Thanks for advance.

Comment: For injectivity, the derivative must be strictly positive or strictly negative (since the derivative is a quadratic, this is easy). Surjectivity will follow at once since this is a cubic equation (as $x\to\pm\infty$, we necessarily have $f(x)\to\pm\infty$).

Comment: Derivate and find the value of $a$ for which the function is strictly increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f'(x)=x^2+\frac{10}3x+a$. Which values of $a$ will make $f$ strictly increasing?

Comment: Why not strictly decreasing as well?

Comment: It could not be strictly decreasing because it is a parabola that opens upward (referring to the derivative of $f(x)$ ). @prog_SAHIL

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Are you aware of many third degree polynomials with dominant coefficient greater than $0$ which are strictly decreasing?

Comment: My bad. Sorry...